# Connect phone fs via usb transfer files

Tags: usb, phone

**System**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-25-lowlatency #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 13:08:53 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Phone**

```
Huawei P10 Lite
Android 8.0.0
```

**Issue**

In Thunar, I can't connect filesystem via usb transfer files. When I connect phone via usb, it shows me in Thunar just `HiSuite`, but no filesystem. For other phones same problem, Thunar is not display filesystem. Before it worked with no problems.

**I tried**

I install `mtp-tools`, `mtpfs` is not in repository.

What service I need to install for this?

Thanks.

**Update**

I tried install `gvfs-*`, but no effect.

**Update 2**

Output of `lsusb`.

Not connected.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Connected.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:107e Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: You may need to enable USB file sharing on your phone first. By default in recent android versions, plugging in USB only powers the phone. From the notification screen, you need to enable other functionality.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, I do it every time I connect phone via usb, changing that option to file transfer, but no effect, still visible just `HiSuite`. As I wrote, it works before without problem.

Comment: Can you show `lsusb` with your phone connected. Maybe we need some udev magic.

Comment: @nobody Hi, info updated in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have gvfs-backends on your System.

search with

```
grep 107e /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

If your device is in the 69-libmtp udev rule.

If not create the file /etc/udev/rules.d/90-huawei.rules
with following content.

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="107e", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Let udev read his rules with `sudo udevadm control -R`

Plugin your phone again. Don't forget to enable  USB file sharing again. Run

```
mtp-detect
```

Any errors?

but I'm running ubuntu bionic.

Comment: Hi, rule file already existed. Seems that `sudo udevadm control -R` helped, now it works. In case of another phone, how could I run `udevadm` automatically? Or will it be necessary in future? Thanks.

Comment: This is wired. Normally when you plugin any Hardware  for example on usb,  udev,  should recive from Kernel an event and read all udev-rules and act.  HiSuite is mounted like a virtual-cd in my cause. But mtp is in linux a little bit unstable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.

Looked for an answer here, found it unclear.
I got mine to show the phones content and transfer as well.

You need to unlock you phone, so you have access to "Developer options" in "System & update".

To unlock "Developer options", enter "Settings". Find and tap "About phone". Tap "Build number" 7 times.
It will ask for you "lock screen password".

You now have access to "Developer options".

Open "Settings" find and tap "System & updates". Tap "Developer options".

The find "Select USB configuration". It will probably be on "Charge only", set it to "Media Transfer Protocol (MTP).

That is how I got access to my contents on the phone, as well as could transfer contents to the phone.

Hope it helps.

- When done:

1. Might want to reset the "Select USB configuration" back to "Charge only".
2. As well as, remove "Developer options", found at the top in "Developer options".